# pyinstall error pyi_rth_qt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am build a python program by using pyqt5 and matplotlib. it is work. and I use the pyinstaller to build a executable file. it is work on my win10 and other win10. but when the win7 open it, it will have error said failed to executable script pyi_rth_qt5. I do not know what is wrong? can someone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzxbO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

1 Pack the program in debug mode, like:

```
pyinstaller --debug -c -F main.py
```

You will get detailed information  when execute the main.exe in cmd.

2 The win7 machine may not have the vs2015 runtime dll, try to install vc_redist 2015.